# What problems do JavaScript Classes solve?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

What was the necessity to invent a class object, was it the result of the DRY concept or does it solve a particular problem?

Comment: It's just another structure... a developer tool to make it easier to write code that fits many different kinds of needs.  Is there a specific question you have about it?

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the answer. And yes, as a beginner learner, I was watching a JavaScript tutorial on building a calculator(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j59qQ7YWLxw). I just couldn't wrap my mind around the reason instructor would use class in his project. And in this class object the key: value pairs are previous and current digit in calculator. Apologies for  my grammar.

Comment: In a tutorial, I imagine the instructor was getting you familiar with the concept.  You should post a new question with a question on specific code.  It's difficult for us to know what part of this ~38 minute video you're asking about specifically.  Stack Overflow questions require that you put the relevant code in the question itself.  That way, you don't have to worry about links disappearing in the future.

Comment: OK, Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's an easier and more readable way of doing this:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}

Person.prototype.name = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
```

As a class:

```
class Person {
  constructor(first, last, age, eyecolor){
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
  }
  
  name() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  };
}
```